# Лучший способ получить указатель на указатель содержащийся в shared_ptr

Tags: c++, указатели

есть legacy функция:

```
void abc(char ** c);
```

и есть современный код вида:

```
std::shared_ptr<char> ptr;
```

каким образом можно наиболее идиоматично повторить такой вызов:

```
char* ptr = "asd";
abc(&ptr);
```

Comment: А что делает `abc`? Двойной указатель подразумевает модификацию `char*`, но насколько это действительно нужно?

Comment: **SharedPtr** - это не указатель, а класс, который занимается сборкой мусора. Считает клиентов, которые пользуются этим указателем, и вычёркивает их потом. Это большая лишняя нагрузка на процессор. Если программа плохо написана, то сборщик мусора добавит свои проблемы. Хорошо написанная программа не нуждается в стороннем контроле за их ресурсами.

Answer (score 2):

Я тут давал ответ...
Но чем больше я о нем размышляю, тем больше нахожу подводных камней.

Поэтому я все же склоняюсь к тому, чтоб сказать - **в общем случае - никак**. Потому что указателем владеет `shared_ptr`, а вы хотите его у него отобрать полностью - а стандартного способа сделать это так, чтоб он не освободил память (если только он изначально не был создан таким, с *неудаляющим удалителем*) - я не вижу. И если `abc` освобождает память - все получается очень нехорошо.

Особенно нехорошо, что С++ работает через `new`, а старинный код, вероятно, через `malloc`, что формально тоже вносит свои неприятности.

Поэтому мое мнение - не использовать `shared_ptr` вместе с `abc` - пользуйте обычный указатель.

---

Поскольку уже пару человек поставили +, вроде неэтично удалять то, за что они это ставили... Так что старый ответ я оставляю, но считаю его не совсем верным - только разве если `abc` память по указателю не удаляет.

Пожалуй,

```
char* tmp = ptr.get();
abc(&tmp);
ptr.reset(tmp);
```

Но, imho, все равно такие фокусы чреваты неприятностями, надо очень внимательно смотреть/понимать 1. что делается в `abc` и 2. не может ли это как-то отразиться на остальных экземплярах `shared_ptr`...

Так что, пожалуй, более безопасно будет

```
char* tmp = ptr.get();
ptr.reset();
abc(&tmp);
ptr.reset(tmp);
```

**А вообще, не стоит мешать французский с нижегородским и смешивать в одном коде два подхода.**

P.S. Если кто-то считает, что лучше ответ удалить совсем - не стесняйтесь указать в комментариях; так и сделаю.